# What bundler/installer of Python applications should I use?

Tags: python, installer

I need a bundler or installer of Python applications. The feature I need are:

- create executable/installer for MacOS
- create executable/installer for Windows
- executables/installer files need to be encrypted

Alternatives looked at so far:

- [fman build system](https://build-system.fman.io/): no option cause it depends on pyinstaller (see comment below)
- [py2exe](https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/): no option cause no support for encryption
- [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/): no option cause encryption is buggy for `<Python3.6` and not supported for `>=Python3.6`

Comment: Maybe cx_freeze? https://pypi.org/project/cx-Freeze/